# Laptop fan too noisy and fast

Tags: 12.04, dell, fancontrol

I'm new to the Ubuntu desktop. The main reason for my question is that I have a Dell Latitud E 6420, and the fan is too fast and noisy or too slow.
I have already read about pwm config, but I would like something more automated, because I’m afraid I might screw up. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I have already followed the instruction for the sensors, but it didn't change much, I didn't have this problem with windows but I hope somebody can help.

Comment: I had such issue. The problem was with open source video drivers. Once I switched to proprientary (ATI Radeon) drivers -- the problem has gone.

Comment: @Adobe Why not add the comment as an answer, you'll need to add a bit more detail like where to find the driver settings etc, but it could be more useful to the user. I agree, it is more than likely that this is the problem.

Comment: What graphics driver are you using? Go to System Settings>Details>Graphics. This will tell you which Graphics drivers you are using, edit your original question and add this info to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Adobe I don't think that applies here. [Its specs](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/dell-latitude-e6420-14/4507-3121_7-34557512.html) suggest it's just using integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: Is the problem fan control, or is the fan running fast because the laptop is overheating? If you install something like 'Psensor' from the software centre this should give you an idea of the temperature just to double check what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I installed proprietary video drivers. System Settings->Software and Updates->Additional Drivers.

For nvidia you can just open a terminal and type: sudo apt-get install nvidia-current